# Matrix of linear operator with respect to canonical basis

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

This is part of a theorem on conformal maps in Freitag's complex analysis that I am unable to prove
[image]

Comment: What is *your* question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T(1,0)=(a,b)$, then, since $\bigl\langle(1,0),(0,1)\bigr\rangle=0$, you know that $\bigl\langle T(1,0),T(0,1)\bigr\rangle=0$ and therefore $T(0,1)$ is orthogonal to $(a,b)$. But then $T(0,1)=(-\lambda b,\lambda a)$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb R$. So$$[T]_\beta=\begin{bmatrix}a&-\lambda b\\b&\lambda a\end{bmatrix},$$and therefore $\det[T]_\beta=\lambda(a^2+b^2)$. Since we are assuming that $\det T>0$, it follows that $\lambda>0$.

Finally, let $x=(1,0)$ and $y=(1,1)$. Then $\bigl\langle(1,0),(1,1)\bigr\rangle=1$ and therefore$$\frac{\bigl\langle(1,0),(1,1)\bigr\rangle}{\lVert(1,0)\rVert.\lVert(1,1)\rVert}=\frac1{\sqrt2}.$$But then$$\frac{\bigl\langle T(1,0),T(1,1)\bigr\rangle}{\lVert T(1,0)\rVert.\lVert T(1,1)\rVert}=\frac1{\sqrt2}$$too. But\begin{align}\frac{\bigl\langle T(1,0),T(1,1)\bigr\rangle}{\lVert T(1,0)\rVert.\lVert T(1,1)\rVert}&=\frac{a^2+b^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sqrt{(1+\lambda^2)(a^2+b^2)}}\\&=\frac1{\sqrt{1+\lambda^2}}.\end{align}Since $\lambda>0$ and $\frac1{\sqrt{1+\lambda^2}}=\frac1{\sqrt2}$, $\lambda=1$.

Comment: thanks , this is really helpful